# Laptop suddenly off without notice the battery level

Tags: laptop, operating-systems, battery-life, poweroff

My laptop is HP Probook 4540s and running on Widows 7 32bit OS. My battery may be week now. But the problem is Laptop suddenly off without notice the battery level. Not shutting down or hibernateing. Is this happening because of weak battery or some OS problem?

Comment: @Nifle Thanks for editting. Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Don't worry about your english. As long as we understand each other it's good enough. Have you checked if your laptop shuts down because it overheats? Try cleaning out it's fans.

Comment: No. It is not overheating. My battery recharged quickly. In system tray battery icon show normal icon. Not the icon with cross (in win7). Actually it doesn't shut down, Power off